# Is there a reason there is inconsistent behavior when doing a search on an elastic index after it is reindexed?

Tags: python, list, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-py

I am using the `elasticsearch` python API and when doing a search on an index that was recently reindexed I see some behavior where I sometimes get results, and sometimes don't. The only way to reproduce this behavior is running the code over and over again until failure, and the same result being seen.

```
es.reindex({"source": {"index": "initial-index"},
            "dest": {"index": "dest-index"}
            }, 
    wait_for_completion=True, refresh=True)

dest_index_results = es.search(index="dest-index", size=100)
hits = get_hits(dest_index_results['hits']['hits'])
```

The `dest_index_results` and `hits` would come out to be empty. Any help understanding why would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have replicas?
If so, maybe your query hit the other server where the data are not yet replicated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a config in index setting called `refresh_interval` . base on the time you set in  this config, the docs will be searchable. for example if the time is set to 1 minute, the docs will be ready for search , one minute after indexing.

you can change this setting with below command;

```
PUT /twitter/_settings
{
    "index" : {
        "refresh_interval" : "10s"
    }
}
```